# QGIS crashes after script is run for the second time

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis, geometry, qgis-3

QGIS Version - 3.0.1

I am trying to create a shapefile with geometry set to 'Point' and SHPT set to 'Point'. But before that I am facing following problems.

1. When I run the below script through QGIS, it gives me following error the first time.

```
    exec(open('C:/Arundhati/Automation Test Script/Radio Signal/QGIS_Test.py'.encode('utf-8')).read())
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
        exec(code, self.locals)
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
    AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'layer'
```

2. When I run the same script second time, QGIS crashes.
3. When I run the same script through OSGEO4W shell, it runs without any errors but I never prints the messages in the print statement. So I am not sure if it is running the script properly.

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\bin>python-qgis.bat "C:\Arundhati\Automation Test Script\Radio Signal\QGIS_Test.py"
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\bin>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Following is the entire script which is causing trouble.

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
import sys

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.0", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False) ###
qgs.initQgis() ###

_layer1 = QgsVectorLayer(
             "C:/Arundhati/Automation Test Script/Radio Signal/SIGNAL.shp",
             "SIGNAL",
             "ogr")

print("I am here" + _layer1.layer.wkbType())


_writer1 = QgsVectorFileWriter(
             "C:/Arundhati/Automation Test Script/Radio Signal/SIGNAL.shp", 
             'utf-8',
             _layer1.fields(),
             Qgis.WKBPoint,
             QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(),
             'ESRI Shapefile')

#add a feature
fet = QgsFeature()
fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(10,10)))
fet.setAttributes([1,"text"])
_writer1.addFeature(fet)

del _writer1

qgs.exitQgis()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use `_layer1.wkbType()` instead of `_layer1.layer.wkbType()` in `print` statement. In your script, `_layer` is already a layer (QgsVectorLayer) and a layer has no `layer` property/attribute. The error states that.
2. If you use different types in `print` statement, you must convert all to string.

   `print("I am here" + str(_layer1.wkbType()))`
3. According to QGIS 3 API, [QgsPointXY Class](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPointXY.html) represents points in 2D and [QgsPoint Class](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPoint.html) represents points with z-dimension and m-values.
4. `layer1 = QgsVectorLayer(...` line opens the file. You try to override the same file while it's open. Use different file name and add `del _layer1` line under `del _writer1` line.
5. In QGIS 3, geometry types is specified by `QgsWkbTypes` enum in `core` library. Thus, you can remove `import qgis.utils`. And change `QGis.WKBPoint` into `QgsWkbTypes.Point`

Briefly, change highlighted lines (`####`) in your script. Then try.

```
from qgis.core import *
# import qgis.utils # <- REMOVE THIS LINE ####
import sys

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.0", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

_layer1 = QgsVectorLayer(
             "C:/Arundhati/Automation Test Script/Radio Signal/SIGNAL.shp",
             "SIGNAL",
             "ogr")

print("I am here" + str(_layer1.wkbType())) #### 1, 2


_writer1 = QgsVectorFileWriter(
             "C:/Arundhati/Automation Test Script/Radio Signal/SIGNAL2.shp", #### 4
             'utf-8',
             _layer1.fields(),
             QgsWkbTypes.Point, #### 5
             _layer1.crs(), ####
             'ESRI Shapefile')

#add a feature
fet = QgsFeature()
fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(10,10))) #### 3
fet.setAttributes([1,"text"])
_writer1.addFeature(fet)

del _writer1
del _layer1  #### 4

qgs.exitQgis()
```

Comment: Sorry. That was my mistake. But even after correcting it I get error :exec(open('C:/Arundhati/Automation Test Script/Radio Signal/QGIS_Test.py'.encode('utf-8')).read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
TypeError: must be str, not Type

Comment: even if I comment that line, still QGIS crashes on the second run.

Comment: I editted the answer. Please check and let me know whether it works or not.

Comment: Done. It gives me following now : Layer was loaded successfully!
ERROR 1: C:/Arundhati/Automation Test Script/Radio Signal/SIGNAL.shp is not a di
rectory.
Error: type object 'QgsGeometry' has no attribute 'fromPoint'          but QGIS still crashes on second run.

Comment: Hmm. `fromPoint` method changed `fromPointXY` in QGIS 3. I've realized now. Link: [fromPointXY()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a81306181071ffa590d0553a7f37dc654)

Comment: Ok. Thank you. That was tough.  Here is the log of latest execution :                                                                          C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\bin>python-qgis.bat "C:\Arundhati\Automation Test Scri
pt\Radio Signal\QGIS_Test.py"
Layer was loaded successfully!
ERROR 1: C:/Arundhati/Automation Test Script/Radio Signal/SIGNAL.shp is not a di
rectory.
ERROR 10: Pointer 'hLayer' is NULL in 'OGR_L_GetLayerDefn'.

ERROR 10: Pointer 'hDefn' is NULL in 'OGR_F_Create'.

ERROR 10: Pointer 'hFeat' is NULL in 'OGR_F_SetGeometryDirectly'.

I reached here

Comment: Why do you use the same name to save as the file?

Comment: No reason. Should they be different always?

Comment: `layer1 = QgsVectorLayer(...`  line opens the file. You try to override the same file while it's open.  I suggests using different file name and adding `del _layer1` line under `del _writer1` line.

Comment: Yes. it worked when I used the different name. Thank you for your patience and suggestins

Comment: OK then. I editted the answer. I added changes stated in comments

Comment: In the same way can you tell me how to set the geometry to lineString?